# how to split a 2d array into multiple 2d arrays of different sized in java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, pixel

I have a 6*6 2d array called pixels

```
  int [][] pixels = { {1,2,7,9,4,11},
                    {3,4,6,6,12,12},
                    {4,9,15,14,9,9},
                    {10,10,20,18,8,8},
                    {4,3,17,16,1,4},
                    {4,5,18,18,5,6}
            };
```

and I want to store its data into 9 2d arrays of size 2*2 like this

```
 int [][] array1 = {{1,2},
            {3,4}
    };

    int [][] array2 = {{7,9},
            {6,6}
    };

    int [][] array3 = {{4,11},
            {12,12}
    };
```

and like this, I have another 2d array of size 320 * 320 which I want to store its data in 6400 2d arrays of size 4*4 and I don't know what is the dynamic to do. my for loops aren't right. Can anyone help?
edit: I tried this code and it gives me the right result regrading the first array of the 2d array but I'm not sure about the second one.
vectorHeight is 4. the big 2d array size is 320* 320 and the smaller ones size is 4 * 4

```
for(int j=0; j < 320  ; j++){
            for(int i=0; i< 320 ; i++){
                int[][] array = new int[][]{
                        {pixels2[j * vectorHeight][i * vectorHeight], pixels2[j * vectorHeight][(i * vectorHeight) + 1],pixels2[j * vectorHeight][(i * vectorHeight) + 2],pixels2[j * vectorHeight][(i * vectorHeight) + 3]},
                        {pixels2[(j * vectorHeight) + 1][i * vectorHeight], pixels2[(j * vectorHeight) + 1][(i * vectorHeight) + 1],pixels2[(j * vectorHeight) + 2][(i * vectorHeight) + 2],pixels2[(j * vectorHeight) + 3][(i * vectorHeight) + 3]},
                };
                         System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
                }
            }
```

edit2: the 320 * 320 2d array is a result of a function that takes an image and return the pixels vector so this is the code for reading an image:

```
public static int[][] readImage(String filePath) {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        BufferedImage image = null;
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();
        int[][] pixels = new int[height][width];
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                int p = image.getRGB(x, y);
                int a = (p >> 24) & 0xff;
                int r = (p >> 16) & 0xff;
                int g = (p >> 8) & 0xff;
                int b = p & 0xff;

                pixels[y][x] = r;

                p = (a << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
                image.setRGB(x, y, p);
            }

        }

        return pixels;
    }
```

and the image that I am currently working on is this one https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Ayman-Al-Dmour/publication/304496637/figure/fig1/AS:377628822392833@1467045135613/Test-images_Q320.jpg
the rest of the code is a function that takes an image, a vector size - height and weight- and eventually its suppose to compress it using vector quantization

```
int [][] pixels = readImage(filePath);
int numofVectors1 = (pixels.length * pixels.length) / (vectorHeight * vectorWidth);
        ArrayList<int[][]> vectors = new ArrayList<>(numofVectors1);
         for (int j = 0; j < pixels.length; j++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
                    int[][] array = new int[][]{
                            {pixels[j * vectorHeight][i * vectorHeight], pixels[j * vectorHeight][(i * vectorHeight) + 1], pixels[j * vectorHeight][(i * vectorHeight) + 2], pixels[j * vectorHeight][(i * vectorHeight) + 3]},
                            {pixels[(j * vectorHeight) + 1][i * vectorHeight], pixels[(j * vectorHeight) + 1][(i * vectorHeight) + 1], pixels[(j * vectorHeight) + 1][(i * vectorHeight) + 2], pixels[(j * vectorHeight) + 1][(i * vectorHeight) + 3]},
                    };
                    vectors.add(array);
                }

        }
```

Comment: "*my for loops aren't right*" post your code so we can help you

Comment: I tried but all my loops were so wrong so they were deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case it's helpful to write down what you want:

```
         [0][0] [0][1] [1][0] [1][1]
         [0][2] [0][3] [1][2] [1][3]
         [0][4] [0][5] [1][4] [1][5]

         [2][0] [2][1] [3][0] [3][1]
         [2][2] [2][3] [3][2] [3][3]
         [2][4] [2][5] [3][4] [3][5]

         [4][0] [4][1] [5][0] [5][1]
         [4][2] [4][3] [5][2] [5][3]
         [4][4] [4][5] [5][4] [5][5]
```

Maybe you can already see a pattern here.
First, I created the inner loop for the first three lines:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    int[][] array = new int[][]{
            {pixels[0][i * 2], pixels[0][(i * 2) + 1]},
            {pixels[1][i * 2], pixels[1][(i * 2) + 1]}
    };
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
}
```

As you see, it's always the zeroth and first row for the first three lines.
And in the next three lines, it's always the second and thrird row.
And the rule for all columns is that it's always zero, two, four and one, three, five.

So it comes to the nested loop:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        int[][] array = new int[][]{
            {pixels[j * 2][i * 2], pixels[j * 2][(i * 2) + 1]},
            {pixels[(j * 2) + 1][i * 2], pixels[(j * 2) + 1][(i * 2) + 1]}};
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
    }
}
```

Now you can store the created arrays for example in a list.

**EDIT**

Sorry, I think I made a mistake. This should do what you want:
create 6400 4x4 arrays. So you have to loop until the square root of the number of arrays you want(in this case 6400).
Do you have a possibility to check if the arrays are correct now?
Try this:

```
int vectorHeight = 4, vectorWidth = 4;
int numofVectors1 = (pixels.length * pixels.length) / (vectorHeight * vectorWidth);
ArrayList<int[][]> vectors = new ArrayList<>(numofVectors1);
int numberOfArrays = 6400;
        for (int j = 0; j < Math.sqrt(numberOfArrays); j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < Math.sqrt(numberOfArrays); i++) {
                int[][] array = new int[][]{
                        {
                                pixels[j * vectorHeight][i * vectorHeight],
                                pixels[j * vectorHeight][(i * vectorHeight) + 1],
                                pixels[j * vectorHeight][(i * vectorHeight) + 2],
                                pixels[j * vectorHeight][(i * vectorHeight) + 3]
                        },
                        {
                                pixels[(j * vectorHeight) + 1][i * vectorHeight],
                                pixels[(j * vectorHeight) + 1][(i * vectorHeight) + 1],
                                pixels[(j * vectorHeight) + 1][(i * vectorHeight) + 2],
                                pixels[(j * vectorHeight) + 1][(i * vectorHeight) + 3]
                        },
                        {
                                pixels[(j * vectorHeight) + 2][i * vectorHeight],
                                pixels[(j * vectorHeight) + 2][(i * vectorHeight) + 1],
                                pixels[(j * vectorHeight) + 2][(i * vectorHeight) + 2],
                                pixels[(j * vectorHeight) + 2][(i * vectorHeight) + 3]
                        },
                        {
                                pixels[(j * vectorHeight) + 3][i * vectorHeight],
                                pixels[(j * vectorHeight) + 3][(i * vectorHeight) + 1],
                                pixels[(j * vectorHeight) + 3][(i * vectorHeight) + 2],
                                pixels[(j * vectorHeight) + 3][(i * vectorHeight) + 3]
                        },
                };
                vectors.add(array);
            }
        }
```

Comment: thank you so much. but this solution only works for this example but the 320 * 320 example - I have another 2d array of size 320 * 320 which I want to store its data in 6400 2d arrays of size 4*4  -will need another code which will also be static. in my program i am taking the size - 4*4- from the user so I'm looking for an algorithm to work on different sizes.

Comment: This would be similiar... instead of looping until 3, use 320.
And instead of 2*2 you have to implement 4*4, which also will have a algorithm. Write down the first few lines and you will see the algorithm

Comment: i did and i get the right results regarding the first array of the 2d array and the second I did a different result here's the code:

Comment: `int[][] array = new int[][]{
                        {pixels2[j * vectorHeight][i * vectorHeight], pixels2[j * vectorHeight][(i * vectorHeight) + 1],pixels2[j * vectorHeight][(i * vectorHeight) + 2],pixels2[j * vectorHeight][(i * vectorHeight) + 3]},
                        {pixels2[(j * vectorHeight) + 1][i * vectorHeight], pixels2[(j * vectorHeight) + 1][(i * vectorHeight) + 1],pixels2[(j * vectorHeight) + 2][(i * vectorHeight) + 2],pixels2[(j * vectorHeight) + 3][(i * vectorHeight) + 3]},
                };`

Comment: vector height is 4

Comment: could you please add the code in your question so it's more readable?

Comment: I did. I'm so sorry for annoying you.

Comment: I updatet my answer, does it work?

Comment: yes!! thank you so much

Comment: it gives me this exception though, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 320 out of bounds for length 320

Comment: Could you please post a minimal reproducible example in your question? So that I can copy and run the code to see the error

Comment: yes of course. I just did.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer. Could you check if the array is correct now?